# Display both reduced amount and also percentage in cart page

Tags: price, special-price

http://www.customy.com/blog/show-product-discount-percent-in-magento/

The amount reduced will be shown in percentage in above link.

I need to display percentage of discount along with "HOW MUCH PRICE SAVED

IN NUMBER", as like this :

You Save: 5,810.00 (18%)

[amazon.com](http://www.amazon.in/gp/product/B00MUESIQC/ref=s9_ri_gw_g147_i4?pf_rd_m=A1VBAL9TL5WCBF&pf_rd_s=center-4&pf_rd_r=16FKCDG0E3W5MXATEVSF&pf_rd_t=101&pf_rd_p=525630627&pf_rd_i=1320006031)

what changes I have to do for this.

please help me to find solution.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

goto 
`app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/` and copy `price.phtml`to `app/design/frontend/Your_theme/default/template/catalog/product/` now in `price.phtml` find for this code

```
<?php endif; /* if ($_finalPrice == $_price): */ ?>
```

above this code add following code

```
<?php if($_finalPrice < $_price): ?>
    <?php 
    $_savePercent = 100 - round(($_finalPrice / $_price) * 100); 
    $_saveAmount = number_format(($_price - $_finalPrice), 2);  
    ?>
        <p class="yousave">
            <span class="price-label label">You Save: </span>
            <span class="price">
                <strong class="save-amount">$<?php echo $_saveAmount; ?></strong> (<?php echo $_savePercent; ?>%)
            </span>
        </p>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: for this line : <strong class="save-amount">$<?php echo $_saveAmount; ?></strong> (<?php echo $_savePercent; ?>%) , I want to use only one echo statement with smae output. please edit the code and paste here.... thanks a lot in advance....