# display percentage of discount on product list and product view page in magento1.9.1.1?

Tags: magento-1.9, product-images

display percentage of discount on product list and product view page in magento1.9.1.1?[image: percentage]

In the beside of product cost will display the percentage

[image: price]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Display both reduced amount and also percentage in cart page](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/50274/display-both-reduced-amount-and-also-percentage-in-cart-page)

Answer (score 3):

If you wish to show product discount percent next to product price or somewhere on a product page, here’s how you do it.

Open

app/design/frontend/**yourpackage/yourtheme**/template/catalog/product/price.phtml

Find: (line 397)

```
<?php endif; /* if ($_finalPrice == $_price): */ ?>
```

Past above it:

```
<?php // Discount percents output start ?>
    <?php if($_finalPrice < $_price): ?>
    <?php $_savePercent = 100 - round(($_finalPrice / $_price)*100); ?>
        <p class="special-price yousave">
            <span class="label"><?php echo $this->__('You Save:') ?></span>
            <span class="price">
                <?php echo $_savePercent; ?>%
            </span>
        </p>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php // Discount percent output end ?>
```

[Link](https://gist.github.com/ViniciusAugusto/b8294e56bfcbde8456d3)

or try to use

[display percentage of discount on product list and product view page in magento](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/60340/display-percentage-of-discount-on-product-list-and-product-view-page-in-magento)

Comment: i did n;t have the price on that place

Comment: i tried to place an image how here?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use **Catalog Price Rule** for product price discount from 
admin -> Promotions -> Catalog Price Rules interface.

[image]